# How to get wider output of tooltip

Tags: yii2, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

As you can see at following picture, tooltip is to narrow, it should be wider, because I want to be able to see all data of database. Any ideas how to extend tooltip?

[image]

Here is code of tooltip

```
[
    'attribute' => $dummy,
    'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Charakterisierung'),
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function($model) {
        if (!empty($model->person->personentypDominant->typ_name)) {
            $tag = Html::tag('span', 'Tooltip-Touch Me!', [
                        // html-tags will be rendered in title using jquery
                        'title' => $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_empfehlung,
                        'data-placement' => 'left',
                        'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
                        'style' => 'white-space:pre;border:1px solid red;'
            ]);
            return $tag . "<br>" . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_im_team_1 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_bei_stress_3 . "," . $model->person->personentypDominant->typ_verhaltensmerkmal_am_arbeitsplatz_4;
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: can you add a sample content from the database that you are rendering , the same string that you have shown in the above image in the question

Comment: and you have added `jquery-ui` tag whereas it is a `bootstrap` tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a css class to override the `max-width` property set on the `.tooltip-inner` class which shows your content as tooltip it is set to default at `200px;`

for example, consider the below `HTML` with ul li, as the tooltip content

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>some point</li>
  <li>some point</li>
  <li>some point</li>
  <li>some point</li>
  <li>some point</li>
</ul>
```

add the following css classes to the view

```
$css = <<<CSS
        .tooltip-inner ul{
            list-style-type:none;
            padding:0; 
            margin:0;
            width:100%;
        }
        .tooltip-inner{
            max-width:700px !important;
        }
CSS;

$this->registerCss($css);
```

this will show you the tooltip like below

[image]

Comment: This will not work for me. Maybe another faulty JavaScript-file?

Comment: have you added the css classes and is there any other class currently applied to the tooltip ? it a css related issue not js try adding `!important` with all the properties if there is any other class overriding the tooltip content @tklustig

Comment: I didn't include explicitly another CSS class in tooltip. Furthermore I integrated code as being shown up from U . HTML code is same, too ! By now, I use popover instead tooltip in order to get all content of database, until ur solution will work!

Comment: ... so, I coded - for instance- .popover-inner ul{  instead .tooltip-inner ul{

Comment: yeah you can change the name to whatever is currently applicable, the main thing is to control it via css @tklustig